# Accidentally Modified tkinter Module: How to Restore Original State?

Tags: python, tkinter, init

I’ve accidentally deleted all the content in the __init__.py and commandialog.py file in python tkinter.
Someone please tell me how to overcome or just give me the code so I can paste it.

I am expecting to get a code or a method.

Comment: Re-install Python (if in Windows) or the required *system* package (if in Linux or MacOS).

Comment: The better/safer approach is in the comment above but: The official python source code is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython). There you can navigate to the python version (one of the git branches), then go to `Lib/tkinter/` and you will find the source code for both python files you deleted.